# What is the correct flag for a SO question asked on Meta SO?

Tags: discussion, flags, close-reasons, meta

Everyday a bunch of SO programming questions end up on meta. As meta is pretty quick I rarely have to flag them as they get closed in the blink of an eye.

But every time I do flag them, I just don't know what the correct flag should be:

[image: flag dialog]

Flag 1, 2, and 4 look applicable in this situation.

1 and 4 are almost identical. 2 has better wording, "*If you have encountered a problem on one of our sites, please describe it in detail*", which may lead to a better understanding of why it's off topic at meta rather than 1 or 4.

While all 3 link to the same help page, the full title feels adequate in this case.

I understand that the answer to this question may be "It doesn't matter", because meta is active and flags bump things into the close vote queue for direct action.

Comment: A flag or a canned comment on [meta] or [meta.se] saying something directly related to *"Move this to [main] site (usually SO)"* could be useful. It is less cryptic and more friendly to new users.

Comment: @TimurShtatland The questions are usually bad anyway, and not fit for the main site.

Comment: It really doesn’t matter. Pick any “off topic” flag. As Robert says, we typically pick #1. But we also typically delete these so quickly that it just doesn’t matter. There’s no amount of editing that will make them on-topic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first option is the one used by close voters i.e.

> This question does not appear to be about Stack Overflow or the software that powers the Stack Exchange network, within the scope defined in the help center.

Generally there are enough high-rep users that these questions can be closed and deleted fairly quickly.